# Nested query to return productname and count of products with max price

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called products and I'm supposed to use a nested query to return the products name and a count of the number of products that have the max price.
But how am I supposed to return the products name and a count of the products that have the max price? I tried doing SELECT productname and COUNT(productid), but it gave me an error which I saw coming since all productsname's are unique in that they have their own productid's.

Is there a way to do this?

Here a sample of whats in the table:

```
productid | productname | price
1           Thing1        33
2           Thing2        77
3           Thing3        44
4           Thing4        55
5           Thing5        66
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT  ?????
FROM Production.Products
WHERE price =
    (SELECT MAX(price)
        FROM Production.Products);
```

Here's what the result should be according to what was asked:

```
productname | NumberofProductsWithMaxPrice
Thing2        1
```

Comment: Max of what, maximum price in table regardless of product? Different products can have same price? Edit question to show sample data and desired result as text tables.

Comment: What doesn't work about the query you have tried? Looks OK to me (aside from the ???).

Comment: SELECT  productname, COUNT(productid) is what i tried. It gave me an error

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can get a separate row for each product using:

```
select top (1) with ties p.*
from production.products p
order by price desc;
```

If you want the count, a subquery is one method:

```
select count(*)
from (select top (1) with ties p.*
      from production.products p
      order by price desc
     ) p;
```